# c# NetFwTypeLib как заблокировать через фаерволл хостнейм вместо IP

Tags: c#, firewall

как заблокировать через фаерволл хостнейм вместо IP? С IP правило создается

```
    public void AddRule()
    {
        RemoveRule();

        INetFwRule rule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));

        rule.Name = "AdBlocker_TEST_Rule";
        rule.Description = "Block inbound traffic from 192.168.0.2 over TCP port 4000";
        rule.RemoteAddresses = "ru.stackoverflow.com";
        rule.Enabled = true;
        rule.Grouping = "@firewallapi.dll,-23255";
        rule.Profiles = _firewallPolicy.CurrentProfileTypes;
        rule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;

        _firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(rule);
    }

    public void RemoveRule()
    {
        _firewallPolicy.Rules.Remove("AdBlocker_TEST_Rule");
    }
```

(на всякий случай)Ошибка:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in AdBlocker.exe 
Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0xD000000D
```

так же если верить статье [Blocking web sites with Windows Firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall), то через сам юай фаервола добавить хостнейм вполне возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто добавьте конвертирование адреса в IP-адрес.

```
string howtogeek = "ru.stackoverflow.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(howtogeek);

foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
{
   Console.WriteLine(theaddress.ToString());
}
```